# Is it possible to recover data from a VM after running “rm -rf /” on it

Tags: virtual-machine, data-recovery

Just used an `rm -rf /` command on my VM and somehow it just destroyed my data on my physical drive.

The question is: What does rm -rf do in terms of deleting data (I mean does it work just like a **delete button** on any OS) and is it possible to recover data after this command has been used?

Comment: With some good data recovery tool you can get it back. I did this mistake while trying to work while dozing very badly

Comment: In general, *never* run `rm -rf /` for any reason. Some people like to prank “newbies” on forums and chat with that advice and it clearly is a horrible idea and a bad joke.

Comment: Well, firstly, I’m a Mac user and I perfectly know that using the command would render my computer useless and even if I wanted to commit a technological “suicide” the SIP wouldn’t allow me (I know I can disable it, but don’t want to risk my data over some extra “features”). The main and the biggest mistake I’ve ever done in my life is my tendency to forget disabling network sharing (which is why this command is so dangerous when running). So the reason my data was destroyed was because I ran Parallels Desktop and used rm -rf / in Ubuntu while it was connected virtually to my home directory

Answer (score 1):

It's just like a regular file delete, only without the trash can / recycle bin that some OS's have. Therefore it does not overwrite any deleted files, so they might be recoverable for afterwards (as long as nothing else has overwritten them).

You can try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_ext2), it can try to list & then copy deleted (red) files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS, ext2, ext3, ext4... it has the advantage of recovering the file's original name, unlike PhotoRec.

Or you can try [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) (as mentioned in [this question from unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122305/undelete-a-just-deleted-file-on-ext4-with-extundelete):

> extundelete is a utility that can recover deleted files from an ext3 or ext4 partition. The ext3 and ext4 file systems are the most common default file systems in Linux distributions like Mint, Mageia, or Ubuntu. extundelete uses information stored in the partition's journal to attempt to recover a file that has been deleted from the partition. *There is no guarantee that any particular file will be able to be undeleted, so always try to have a good backup system in place, or at least put one in place after recovering your files!*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately rm recursive and force delete files permanently, what you could do it is power down the computer and **try** to recover files from the journal FS (if enable) before they get overwritten by some thing else.

If FS is ext4 here have a guide could help (if you FS is ext4):

http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/howto_en.html

If it is XFS FS seems there have no solutions: http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Does_the_filesystem_have_an_undelete_capability.3F

if you have some data to recover you could also try with [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) but also here it is more about luck to recover all.

I'm sorry for you, I do not know other methods to perform a data recovery.